# ¿Como Acceder a un método privado de una clase interna privada?

Tags: java, clase

¿Como acceder a un método privado de una clase interna privada todo esto dentro de una clase interna estática ?

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    //aca tengo que acceder al metodo powerof2
    } 
    static class Inner{
        private class Private{
            private String powerof2(int num){
               return ((num&num-1)==0)?"power of 2":"not a power of 2";
            }
        }
    }//end of Inner
}//end of Solution
```

Comment: Lo que me genera gran confusión es por qué votan a cerrar esta pregunta. Si carecen del conocimiento para responderla o entenderla técnicamente **no significa** que no esté claro lo que se pregunta.

Answer (score 6):

Para acceder a un método de una clase Privada, hace falta `instanciar` dicha clase primero. algo similar a `Privates Obj = new Privates();` para luego acceder a su método así  `Obj.Metodo();` **Pero** en este caso la clase privada está dentro de una clase `Estática` Por lo que haría necesario crear una Instancia de `Inner` para luego `instanciar` la clase `Privates();`

Recordar que para crear una Instancia de una Clase estática no es necesario crear una Instancia de la Clase Padre `(Solution)`

```
Solution.Inner obj = new Solution.Inner(); /* Instancia de la clase Estatica*/
String valor = obj.new Privates().powerof2(2); /* Creamos la Instancia de la Clase 
                         Privates y luego llamamos al método que retorna Una Cadena */
System.out.println(valor); /* Impresión de lo que retorna el método */
```

Comment: Gracias me sirvio.

Answer (score 3):

Puedes intentar algo como esto:

```
String resultado = Inner.new Private().powerof2(1);
```

¡Suerte!

Answer (score -1):

En este caso intentas acceder a un metodo no estatico de una clase privada que se encuentra dentro de una clase estatica.

Una clase no definida como static, puede acceder al método instanciando la clase y accediendo a su método, instancias primero `Inner` y posteriormente `Private` para acceder a su método `powerof2()`:

```
  //Instancia Inner.
 Solution.Inner inner = new Solution.Inner();
 //Accede a clase Private y a su metodo.
 String valuePowerof2 = inner.new Private().powerof2(12);
```

Este sería el cambio completo :

```
public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     //aca tengo que acceder al metodo powerof2

     //Instancia Inner.
     Solution.Inner inner = new Solution.Inner();
     //Accede a clase Private y a su metodo.
     String valuePowerof2 = inner.new Private().powerof2(12);
     //Imprime valor.
     System.out.print("valor: " + valuePowerof2);

    } 

    static class Inner{
        private class Private{
            private String powerof2(int num){
               return ((num&num-1)==0)?"power of 2":"not a power of 2";
            }
        }
    }//end of Inner
}//end of Solution
```